# PHP Strict standards: What is the non-compliance in this code?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

If i write this code in PHP with Stricts Standarts, i've an non-compliance:

```
class Readable {};
class Atom extends Readable {};

class Reader { 
  public function read(Readable $readable){} 
}

class AtomReader extends Reader { 
  public function read(Atom $readable){} 
}

PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of AtomReader::read() should be compatible with Reader::read(Readable $readable) in php shell code on line 2
```

What is the principle (like SOLId, ...) failure here ?

*Note: if i'm right, this code respect Liskov principle*.

Comment: You linked to a deleted question, how is that helpful?

Comment: @Barmar i thought it was visible for other people than me, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply speaking, *Liskov substitution principle* just states that inheritance should be logical part of a class it inherits from to satisfy `is-a` relationship.

As for strict standards, PHP expects an overridden method to have exactly the same signature as its parent. In your case its a just a different `type-hint`. Instead you should type-hint an interface that both classes do implement.

```
class Reader { 
   public function read(ReadableAtomInterface $readable){} 
}

class AtomReader extends Reader { 
   public function read(ReadableAtomInterface $readable){} 
}
```

Comment: So my code is in compliance with SOLID principles but not with PHP Strict standarts, that's it ?

Comment: Have no idea about SRP, DiP, OCP since I saw only singular prototype of that method. But in terms of LSP - seems like it is..

Comment: About your code, it will be not better with "ReadableInterface" ?: class Reader { public function read(ReadableInterface $readable){} } ; class AtomReader extends Reader { public function read(ReadableInterface $readable){} }

Comment: If its specific exactly to `Atom` - then no, otherwise - yes, it would be

Answer (score 0):

If it is `Reader::read(Readable $readable)`, then the method in child class must use `Readable` too.

```
class AtomReader extends Reader { 
  public function read(Readable $readable){} 
}
```